# Android : Set multiple repeating alarms

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programming. I want to set different repeating alarms. I wrote a code, but it is not working. It is not generating any alarms. Please help me.
Here is my code

```
public void setAlarm(int hour, int min,String am_pm){

    if(hour == 12 && am_pm.equals("am")){
        hour=00;
    }

    if(hour != 12 && am_pm.equals("pm")){
        hour=hour+12;
    }


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlertReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

}

For above I am passing setAlarm(8,30,"am")

Comment: When you create Calendar instance, it's of the current day. Do you run the app before this time that you've set?

Comment: Yeah, I run the app before the alarm time

Comment: Have you tried the sample here: http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html ?

Comment: Yup, I tried, its working, but when I am sending values to setAlarm function, its not working.

Comment: What values? What exactly doesn't work?